# 404 error with custom domain for Google Cloud Run service

Tags: ssl, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, custom-domain

I created a custom domain mapping for my Cloud Run service following this guide https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/mapping-custom-domains.

I can access my service via the https run.app URL and the custom domain via HTTP, but when I go to the custom domain via HTTPS, I get back a Google  404 error page.

The weird thing is, this seems to be an issue on my local laptop (both browser and `curl` on the terminal), but `curl`-ing it from a remote server seems to work ok.

Comment: If you are getting a 404 error, then your HTTPS endpoint is working. A 404 is returned by your web server running inside the container. If DNS or SSL was not working, you could not get a 404. There is something wrong with the code running in your container. Go to Google Stackdriver and check the logs for error messages. Debug and fix your code.

Comment: @JohnHanley I think you're correct, though I don't see any error in my service. It seems like I could access the service via curl from a remote server OK, but somehow loading it on my browser or curl-ing it from my computer is presenting the 404.

Comment: If you can use curl to access your endpoint over HTTPS, example `curl -i https://example.com` but the same URL fails in a browser, then turn on the debugger in the browser and analyze what is happening.

Comment: No, the issue happens on my local laptop, but not on a remote server. Even curl locally gives the 404. But I could access the run.app domain just fine. So I'm not sure where the problem is occurring.

Comment: There's currently an issue affecting the Cloud Run service experiencing intermittent HTTP 404 responses for Cloud Run services with custom domains. I can't provide you with an ETA for resolution but work is ongoing.

Comment: Thanks @LundinCast for the tip. If there's no where I could go to keep up to date with that issue, could you please check back in here if you know when it has been resolved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @LundinCast pointed out, there seems to be an outage on the Google server side. I'll monitor the situation and mark this as resolved for now.

Edit: I'm guessing this is related to https://status.cloud.google.com/incident/cloud-networking/19016