# 404 error when trying to make HTTP request to Cloud Run Container

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-scheduler

I have a GCP project with a pipeline that scrapes a website at regular intervals. It has a cloud scheduler set up that posts to a Run container using an HTTP request (the container does the scraping). However, when I start the scheduler, the Run container logs just show a warning that says "[*some_timestamp*] POST 404 695 B [*execution_time*] Google-Cloud-Scheduler [*Cloud_Run_URL*]". I was confused because the scheduler posted the request to the right Run container, but the container is throwing a 404 error? What might be happening here?

If more information is needed, I will post it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not the container is throwing 404.

A service, your web server on the container throws the 404.

So the request hits the container, then the webserver, but the requested URL doesn't work, and the web server returns 404. Look for your application errors, or if the path exists on the given URL.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no outage occurring with any GCP services, which you can check in [this](https://status.cloud.google.com/) status page. I suggest you try to emulate your Cloud Run container locally following [this](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/testing/local) guide and using the Cloud Run emulation tool to test if the issue originates from your application instead of Cloud Run.

According to this thread [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56862432/404-error-with-custom-domain-for-google-cloud-run-service#comment100274438_56862432), the 404 error might be returning from your web server and it is logged in [Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/troubleshooting#logs). In [this](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/troubleshooting#logs) documentation page there are Cloud Run error codes and their meanings in addition to more troubleshooting procedures.